# mvn jetty:run not reflecting changes when run inside docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, jetty, docker-compose

I have a simple Tic-tac-toe Java web app https://github.com/rajaraodv/tictactoe It is a Maven project. It uses Jetty to run the web app by doing `mvn jetty:run` While it is running locally, I can easily modify a JavaScript file and see the changes immediately when I refresh the browser. But, when I run it via Docker where I am mounting the source directory, similar change doesn't get reflected.

Note: I am mounting the source directory in docker-compose.yml file. And I see the change reflected in the file but jetty doesn't pick up the change.

**Please Note: It needs JDK 7**

To test on localhost:

```
  mvn clean install
  mvn jetty:run
  Open localhost:8080 to see the app.
  Add an alert(1); in `doInit` function in this JavaScript https://github.com/rajaraodv/tictactoe/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/components/ttt/TicTacToeGrid/TicTacToeGridController.js
  Refresh the browser and you'll see an alert dialog
```

To test on Docker (using [Docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)):

```
    docker-compose up
    Add an alert(1); in `doInit` function in [this JavaScript][3]    
    ...Refresh browser, but the change is not reflected
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest to start debugging from checking files permissions (something like `docker exec -it container-id ls -l /usr/src/app`).

Comment: `jetty-maven-plugin` was designed for local development use only.  all other uses are unsupported.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt It is for local development but inside a container.

Comment: @SlavaSemushin Is there anything specific permission I should be looking at?

Comment: BTW, you can test this in ANY jetty app and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In your Dockerfile you do an ADD for source dir.
Instead, specify a volume for that path.
With the dockerfile as you have it it adds the src at container build time, then the mount does not do anything in compose.

Comment: Does this look right? FROM maven:3.3.3-jdk-7
   RUN mkdir --parents /usr/src/app
   ADD . /usr/src/app
   VOLUME /usr/src/app
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app
   RUN mvn clean install
   CMD mvn jetty:run

Comment: btw, if i do: "docker exec -it tictactoe_web_1 bash" I can see the change in the file inside the container. But jetty doesnt pick up the change.